Firebase with network-request-failed when using ios simulator
I'm trying to test my expo app in ios simulator, I always tested with Expo Go in physical device, but when trying to use the ios simulator, when signInWithEmailAndPassword method from firebase, i get the error  network-request-failed.
This happens just calling firebase directly from client, I tried to sign up a new user, calling my api, and it worked well, but callind the signIn in client, didn't
Any help?
Tried to login using firebase method directly from client, expected to login succesfully
